# Problem while returning an array on react: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I am triying to return p in a div from an array that come from a useState hook, but give me this error:Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtFIE.png)

```
function App(){

        
    const [items, setLab] = useState(["a", "b", "c"])

    console.log(items)
    return (
        <div> laberinto
        {this.items.bind(this).map((item) => {
             <div>
                 <p>{item}</p> 
             </div>
         })
        }
        </div>
    )

}

 
render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `App` component is a *functional* component (not a *class* component), so you don't need to use `this` keyword.

```js
{items.map((item) => {
  <div>
    <p>{item}</p>
  </div>
 })
}
```

More detailed about Functional and Class components here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

1. `this` is simply undefined in React function components.
2. `Array.prototype.map` callback needs to return a value being mapped to.

## Solution

- Remove any `this` references.
- Return JSX from the `.map` callback. Don't forget to include the React keys.

Explicit return statement in the function body:

```
function App() {
  const [items, setLab] = useState(["a", "b", "c"]);

  return (
    <div>
      laberinto
      {items.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div key={item}>
            <p>{item}</p> 
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Implicit return without a function body:

```
function App() {
  const [items, setLab] = useState(["a", "b", "c"]);

  return (
    <div>
      laberinto
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div key={item}>
          <p>{item}</p> 
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```